# Transfer tfs Branch code from one tfs server to another

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have two tfs server one is test and other is live, i want to update my test server with live server.

Can someone please suggest how can i do that?

Comment: Do you just want  the source code in test server and no need to keep source control history?

Comment: Any update on this？

Comment: I was able to get to this, by just pulling live server code and staging and commit to test server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you just need the source code and want to move the code in branch from one TFS server to another TFS server.

Just follow below steps:

> 1. Connect to Old TFS server
> 2. Get latest of the code
> 3. Copy all to a new directory.
> 4. Then, open Team explorer and connect to your new server. Open Source
>      Control Explorer by clicking the Source Control Icon.
> 5. Create a new Workspace to your new directory.
> 6. Click the "Add Files" icon in Source Control Explorer and add your
>      files and folders. If you like you can first delete all files you do
>      not want to add like (bin and obj folders)
> 7. Check in changes
> 8. Then...Most important! Open your solution from the Source Control
>      Explorer !! It automatically binds to the new server now

More detail steps and tutorials please refer this link: **[Moving source from one TFS to another](https://roadtoalm.com/2012/10/25/moving-source-from-one-tfs-to-another/)**